# LUIS Intent prediction

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm having trouble with a LUIS Intent prediction. The utterance "consumo" should trigger the intent "1529_CONSULTAR_CONSUMO" but LUIS keeps assigning it to a wrong intent, even though the exact utterance is registered as an example to the right intent. How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problems depends on your model. Because the intent that LUIS associates to one utterance and the score can be affected by any entity or any utterance added on any intent.

You can try :
- Look at the wrong intent "consumo" was associated to and if some utterances are similar to "consumo" maybe the two intents should be the same
- Create a list entity with "consumo" and other entities in the list

Comment: This video shows how you can see overlap between intents: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0018-McrZz0